# Bootstrap exercise I don't understand

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm a new student stuck with a teacher that has some difficulty to teach us clearly. As I am trying to do the exercises, I just find myself with no clue how to achieve anything. This should not be complicated since I just had 4 weeks of school.

Can someone explain to me or give me a clue on how to finish the exercise in the picture?

Thanks!

[image: This is what I should do]

Comment: Notice how the first row gets wrapped on mobile and the second doesn't.

Comment: Read about the responsive grid: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#responsive-classes

Comment: Try to learn and understand the concept from here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ver.asp or if you have any other platform where you understand concept easily.

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 first-col">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 second-col">2</div>
    <div class="col-6 third-col">3</div>
    <div class="col-6 fourth-col">4</div>
    <div class="col-12 fifth-col">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.first-col {
  background: red;
}

.second-col {
  background: blue;
}

.third-col {
  background: green;
}

.fourth-col {
  background: red;
}

.fifth-col {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Explanation:
The first two columns have a width of 6 on sizes bigger than `md` (see docs) and full width on mobile. Columns two and three have a width of six on all screen sizes. The last column have a width of 12 on all screen sizes.

In order to understand how the Bootstrap grid system works, I strongly recommend reading through this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ . This will give you a better understanding of how this code works.

Also, please note that the naming convention is not general good practice, but for the sake of this example, it illustrates better.

Comment: 2 things: 1) it should be `.container-fluid` instead of `.container` because from the screenshot the container takes up the entire screen width. 2) It's worth noting that on the fifth col, even it's always taking up 100% width, you still would like to put `.col-12`, just because the rows from Bootstrap have negative margins and `.col-*` has the matching amount of paddings to accomindate that. Everything else looks good :)